# Equality between images c#

Tags: c#, image

I need to compare two images and see if they are the same.

The images only contain text.

I have an image on the hard drive saved and I need to see if it is the same as the one I am downloading.

I tried with this code to establish a margin of error of 5%, but the main problem I have is that the text of image can be rotated between 0 and 30 degrees or 0 and -30

```
int width;
int height;
if (bmp1.width < bmp2.width)
{
    width = bmp1.width;
}
else
{
    width = bmp2.width;
}
if (bmp1.heigth < bmp2.width)
{
    heigth = bmp1.heigth;
}
else
{
    heigth = bmp2.heigth;
}
int contador = 0;

for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        if (bmp1.GetPixel(x, y) == bmp2.GetPixel(x, y))
        {
            contador++
        }
    }
}
int similar_percent = (contador / (height * width) * 100);
```

I leave two small examples of the images

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are they actually the same just different by the rotation or are they only similar? Both is hard, the latter would probably need ocr, the former a way to find & remove the rotation. Way too broad a question for SO in any case.

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this with simple pixel comparisons. When you try to do it this way, a line moving 1 pixel across will be a 0% match. Find a library to do this for you.

Comment: They are only different by rotation,the problem with ocr  is that I do not want the image to say the same thing, I just want it to be the same

Comment: @GeorgeHelyar Do you know any library that does this?

Comment: Do you know the rotation center?

Comment: If you know that nothing gets cut off and they are all color on white you may try to count the dark/colored pixels; note that any decent rotation alg. will create antialiased pixels as well, so you need to add up the brightness. Still very crude. Ther are libraries to help but you need to ask google, not us!

Comment: have you considered using hashing to do so? or do you have a need to literally check the equality pixel by pixel?

Comment: no I do not have the need to compare each one I just want to measure similarity between images

Comment: @NicoSchertler I have an idea in which I could find out what it is, why?

Comment: I was thinking about factoring out the rotation. If you know the rotation center, this is an optimization problem with one unknown. If you don't know it, you have three. But the ideas that other people mentioned are probably better (i.e., find some rotation-invariant feature descriptors and just compare the descriptors).